# UITabBarController with multiple storyboards

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I am developing an iOS app with Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

I have a **Tab Bar Controller** with one tab view embedded into a **Navigation Controller**, as you see below:

[image: tab bar controller with one tab view]

As the project continues, the storyboard is getting bigger. I really don't like it. So, I would like to divide it into multiple storyboards.

**My question is:**

How to divide a **Tab Bar Controller** & the associated tab's view controllers into multiple storyboards? What is the best practice to do it? And how to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to divide tabbar controller? Why not its upcoming views?

Comment: My question is "How to divide Tab Bar Controller & the associated tab's view controllers into multiple storyboards?", I am not saying divide Tab Bar Controller only. So, only divide upcoming views is also a good suggestion to me.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If your target is ***iOS 9 and above***, you should create **storyboard references** for the view controllers you want to include in another storyboard. Here's how it works:

1. Create a second storyboard, move the desired view controller into it and give it a **Storyboard ID** under the **Identity inspector**.

[image: Identity inspector]

2. Go to your first storyboard and search for **Storyboard Reference** in the Object library.

[image: Object library - Storyboard Reference]

3. Drag it into your storyboard and create a **"view controllers" relationship** with the tab bar controller just like you would with a view controller.

[image: tab bar controller with view controllers in the storyboard]

4. Under the **Storyboard Reference's Attribute inspector**, change your settings accordingly. For **Referenced ID**, use the **view controller's ID** on the second view controller.

[image: the Storyboard Reference's Attribute inspector]

Comment: @Leem.fin This is the **only** solution if you don't want to use any code for setup. You have to keep in mind though that storyboard references require iOS >= 9.

Comment: @AndréSlotta Thanks, I included this in my answer.

Comment: My target is set to 9.0. How are you getting around this error: "Illegal Configuration: Storyboard References cannot be the destinations of relationship segues prior to iOS 9.0"

Comment: the destination VC added but it's not showing tabbar icon. can you help with that?